# Doctrine value object with one field only

Tags: doctrine-orm

Currently I use Doctrine2 with value object, it's working great. The problem when I use value object with only one field, for example:

```
$this->repository->findBy(array('email' => 'name@domain.com')); //This is not working
$this->repository->findBy(array('email.email' => 'name@domain.com')); //This is work great
```

The question is, how to make $this->repository->findBy(array('email' => 'name@domain.com')); working?

This is my doctrine mapping

User.orm.xml

```
<!-- User.orm.xml -->    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                      xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
            http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd"
                      xmlns:gedmo="http://gediminasm.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-extensions-mapping">

        <entity name="Domain\User\Entity\User" table="users" repository-class="Infrastructure\User\Repository\UserRepository">
            <id name="id" type="guid">
                <generator strategy="UUID"/>
            </id>
            <embedded name="email" class="Shared\ValueObject\Email" use-column-prefix="false" />
        </entity>
    </doctrine-mapping>
```

Email.orm.xml

```
<!-- Email.orm.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <embeddable name="Shared\ValueObject\Email">
        <field name="email" type="string" length="80" />
    </embeddable>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to [code](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php#L3310) this is not possible. Field name always be

```
$property . "." . $fieldMapping['fieldName'];
```